# How do I convert a StringReader to a String?

Tags: java, string, tostring, stringreader

I'm trying to convert my `StringReader` back to a regular `String`, as shown:

```
String string = reader.toString();
```

But when I try to read this string out, like this:

```
System.out.println("string: "+string);
```

All I get is a pointer value, like this:

```
java.io.StringReader@2c552c55
```

Am I doing something wrong in reading the string back?

Comment: Clearly, you are. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html

Comment: You can't get the string back from a stringreader without using read(.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `StringReader`'s `toString` method does not return the `StringReader` internal buffers.

You'll need to read from the `StringReader` to get this.

I recommend using the overload of read which accepts a character array.  Bulk reads are faster than single character reads.

ie.

```
//use string builder to avoid unnecessary string creation.
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int charsRead = -1;
char[] chars = new char[100];
do{
    charsRead = reader.read(chars,0,chars.length);
    //if we have valid chars, append them to end of string.
    if(charsRead>0)
        builder.append(chars,0,charsRead);
}while(charsRead>0);
String stringReadFromReader = builder.toString();
System.out.println("String read = "+stringReadFromReader);
```

Comment: See @Kiran's answer for a Java 9+ solution that is much simpler.

Answer (score 27):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

String string = IOUtils.toString(reader);
```

Comment: See @Kiran's answer for a Java 9+ solution that does not use external libraries.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer not to use external libraries:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter("\\A");
 String str = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
```

The reason for the `hasNext()` check is that `next()` explodes with a `NoSuchElementException` if the reader wraps a blank (zero-length) string.

Answer (score 4):

Or using `CharStreams` from Googles Guava library:

```
CharStreams.toString(stringReader);
```

Comment: See @Kiran's answer for a Java 9+ solution that does not use external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/stringwriter_tostring.htm

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("hello");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sr.transferTo(sw);
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

Comment: This is the right answer for Java 10+. Note that Reader gained this method in Java 10 and InputStream gained this method in Java 9. Under the hood, this takes advantage of a character buffer of size 8192 bytes in both cases and uses StringBuffer.append in the StringWriter. This version will not have issues with removing line endings.

Answer (score 1):

`reader.toString();` will give you the results of calling the generic `toString()` method from `Object` class.

You can use the `read()` method:

```
int i;               
do {
    i = reader.read();
    char c = (char) i;
    // do whatever you want with the char here...

} while (i != -1);
```

Comment: A bulk read with an array will be faster than reading a single character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Calling toString() method will give the object of StringReader class. If yo want it's content then you need to call the read method on StringReader like this:

```
public class StringReaderExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String s = "Hello World";

      // create a new StringReader
      StringReader sr = new StringReader(s);

      try {
         // read the first five chars
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            char c = (char) sr.read();
            System.out.print("" + c);
         }

         // close the stream
         sr.close();

      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

For tutorials you can use this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_stringreader.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Another native (Java 8+) solution could be to pass the `StringReader` object to a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) trough the lines:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stringReader)) {
  br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the `toString()` of the actual `StringReader` object, NOT the contents of the `String` that the `StringReader` is reading.

You need to use the `read()` and/or the `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` methods to read the actual chars in the String.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method `toString()` in a `StringReader` object you will print the memory position of the object. You have yo use one of this method:

`read()`
Reads a single character.

`read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`
Reads characters into a portion of an array.

Here an example:

```
     String s = "Hello World";

    // create a new StringReader
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(s);

    try {
        // read the first five chars
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = (char) sr.read();
            System.out.print("" + c);
        }

        // close the stream
        sr.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```