# Tabs cannot be used for indentation when parsing YAML string

Tags: java, yaml, yamlbeans

I have a `byte[]` that represents a UTF-8-encoded YAML string and I want to deserialize it. Here's the generic method I'm using:

```
public static <T> T getInstanceFromBinary(final Class<T> clazz, final byte[] binary, final String encoding)
        throws IOException {
    final StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(new String(binary, encoding));
    final String yamlString = stringReader.toString();
    final boolean hasTab = yamlString.contains("\t");
    final YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(stringReader);
    final T clazzInstance = reader.read(clazz);
    reader.close();
    return clazzInstance;
}
```

and I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.tokenizer.Tokenizer$TokenizerException: Line 185, column 35: Tabs cannot be used for indentation.
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.tokenizer.Tokenizer.fetchMoreTokens(Tokenizer.java:313)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.tokenizer.Tokenizer.peekNextToken(Tokenizer.java:120)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.tokenizer.Tokenizer.peekNextTokenType(Tokenizer.java:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.parser.Parser$20.produce(Parser.java:320)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.parser.Parser.getNextEvent(Parser.java:80)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.parser.Parser.peekNextEvent(Parser.java:91)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:270)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:152)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:295)
    ... 38 more
```

The problem is that the decoded string doesn't seem to contain a tab character. Here's a screenshot from the debug that confirms this:

[image: Debug info]

I've also checked YAMLBeans source code, and [found where](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/yamlbeans/tokenizer/Tokenizer.java#L312) this exception is thrown, although this didn't yield any light about why this is happening or how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: The string does not have any tabs. I checked the string from its source and also after regenerating it from UTF-8.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I'm wrong. The string does contain tabs.

Comment: The actual issue was that one piece of data had a (wrong) tab character on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` on your StringReader which returns the cryptic and rather useless implementation provided by Object.toString(). `java.io.StringReader@329dbdbf` i.e. it doesn't tell you if you have tabs or not.

Instead you need to check the original `String` you used before passing it to StringReader and possibly apply `.replaceAll("\t", "\\t")`

Comment: `StringReader#toString()` actually returns the YAML string just like `StringBuffer` (which is what `StringReader` uses internally IIRC).

Comment: @m0skit0: Your debug screenshot says otherwise. StringBuilder and StringBuffer both return the backed string, but StringReader does not. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751056/how-do-i-convert-a-stringreader-to-a-string

Comment: @m0skit0 not in the version of Java I have nor the version of Java you have according to your debugger. Are you saying `java.io.StringReader@329dbdbf` is your YAML?

Comment: @m0skit0 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html states that toString() is inherited from Object.

Comment: @m0skit0 Peter is right mate, I just checked it too

Comment: Oh damn, sorry, yes, you're totally right. Too many hours with this has fried my brain. I have the extracted the YAML string so I thought I got it from there. And yes, the string does contain tabs, which leads me to the new problem on why it has them... Thanks for your help!

Comment: The actual issue was that one piece of data had a tab character on it. Removing it worked just fine.